# Understanding rails generated URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to Rails and I am trying to understand it.  One thing that mistifies me the urls that rails can generate.  For example, if I have a user controller which is labelled as a :resource in my routes file.  It generates all kinds of urls such as user_path or edit_user_path.

Where can I learn more about these urls that it is generating, how it is doing it and what all the urls, that is does generate, are available to me.

Comment: RailsGuides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Lol,  1 minute and three links to the exact same guide. Google is your friend Josh :) Look to the Rails Guide for all kinds of goodness.

Comment: Don't forget this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Rails Routing from the Outside In" Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is your friend ;)

Answer (score 3):

See the Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

That pretty much explains everything about this.